# Using MERGE with same source/target table in Sql Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, insert

I want to do an Upsert on a table from my python program. I found the MERGE command but that seems to be specific for merging two tables. I want to UPDATE/INSERT a field into a table from one query.

I want something quicker than a DELETE then INSERT or SELECT then [INSERT/UPDATE] and am trying to get MERGE working. However, when I run it in SSMS it is updating *all* the rows in the database table.

The query is:

```
MERGE INTO [LastPriceUpdate] USING 
(SELECT [EventID] FROM [LastPriceUpdate] where [EventID] = 1501845) AS source
ON (source.[EventID] = 1501845)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET [LastPriceUpdate] = getdate() -- where clause not allowed
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ([EventID], [LastPriceUpdate]) VALUES (1501845, getdate());
```

That query updates all rows and I only want it to update the LastPriceUpdate column with getdate() where EventID = {somenumber}

Possible Answer:
This might be a fix; use the target on the ON part.

```
MERGE INTO [LastPriceUpdate] AS target USING 
(SELECT [EventID] FROM [LastPriceUpdate] where [EventID] = 1501845) AS source
ON (target.[EventID] = 1501845)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET [LastPriceUpdate] = getdate() -- where clause not allowed
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ([EventID], [LastPriceUpdate]) VALUES (1501845, getdate());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
MERGE INTO LastPriceUpdate as lpu
USING (
        SELECT getdate() as LastPriceUpdate,
               1501845 as EventID
      ) AS src
ON lpu.EventID = src.EventID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET LastPriceUpdate = src.LastPriceUpdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (EventID, LastPriceUpdate) 
    VALUES (src.EventID, src.LastPriceUpdate);
```